# Фильтрация дубликатов из запроса по полю с приоритезацией

Tags: java, sql, jpa

Нужно реализовать фильтрацию дубликатов в списке по списку приоритетов

Есть класс, составляющий список `List<Trade>`

```
public class Trade { int id, int sectionId, String name, ... }
```

И есть приоритет секций (sectionId) - `List<Integer> priorities = List.of(63, 174, 74, 36, 37, 61, ...)`

Возможна ситуация, когда из репозитория вытянутся строки с одинаковым `id` (2, 3 или больше штук), но с разным `sectionId` и нужно сделать фильтрацию списка `List<Trade>` согласно `priorities`, чтобы в исходном списке (или в новом) остались только строки с уникальными `id`

Пример исходных данных:

```
id, section_id, name
118,36,МБ
163,36,МБ
163,66,ОТС
226,36,МБ
```

В наборе две строки с `id = 163`:

```
163,36,МБ
163,66,ОТС
```

должна быть одна, согласно `priorities` в приоритете `sectionId = 63`, в этих двух строках такого `sectionId` нет, идем по списку дальше пока не попадем на `sectionId = 36`, соответственно берем строку 1:

```
163,36,МБ
```

Итоговый результат должен выглядеть так:

```
id, section_id, name
118,36,МБ
163,36,МБ
226,36,МБ
```

Добавлю, что для вытягивания записей `Trade` используется `JpaRepository` и в качестве БД - MS SQL с native query в репозитории, поэтому если есть способ сделать фильтрацию прямо в запросе, наверное так будет даже лучше

Мое решение на данный момент -

1. вытянуть все записи `Stream<Trade> findAll()`
2. сгруппировать в мапу по id `collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Trade::getId))`;
3. создать список через `stream().flatMap(Collection::stream)`, чтобы было откуда удалять
4. отфильтровать values() по size() > 1
5. в каждом таком списке реализовать `sort()` с компаратором по `priorities`
6. удалить все элементы, кроме первого в исходном списке

В принципе вариант рабочий, но тяжеловесный и как считаю не очень проходит для 2-3к строк

Comment: Постарайтесь привести пример, что и как вы хотите отфильтровать.  К примеру, что должно получиться для данных `[{id=1, section=1}, {id=1, section=2}, {id=2, section=1}, {id=2, section=2}]` и `priorities=[1,2]`?  И что именно у вас считается "дубликатом"?

Comment: @NowhereMan логика верная, дополнил вопрос с данными для более точного понимания

Answer (score 0):

Приведу пример, как понял я (использую postgres, но, думаю, разницы большой не будет).

```
create table public.trade
(
    id         integer      not null,
    section_id integer      not null,
    name       varchar(255) not null
);
```

```
create table trade_priority
(
    id       integer not null,
    priority integer
);
```

Запрос:

```
select t.*
from trade t
         inner join trade_priority tp on tp.id = t.section_id
    and (t.id, tp.priority) in
        (select tr.id, max(tp.priority)
         from trade tr
                  inner join trade_priority tp on tp.id = tr.section_id
         group by tr.id)
```